# DC/DC Buck Converter PCB Layout Help

Tags: pcb, dc, buck, converter, layout

Most examples I find are for buck converters on a PCB of their own with massive traces. I want to make sure this layout is fine with the planes I'm using(both top and bottom copper pour layers are GND).
 I'm using a low output buck converter on a uC board I'm developing. The board will have USB to UART interface, uC, and 900 MHz radio. Total current draw is expected to be 70-100mAh, supply voltage to the board will be 12-30V. I'll leave out all these parts and just focus on the buck and buck components:

Buck: LT3970EMS-5#PBF (350mAh output max,  600Khz frequency). 
Inductor: ASPIAIG-S4035. 
R14 is just choosing frequency. 
Cap values are on layout. 
1uF, 2.2uF, 47uF are Cin. 
22uF is Cout.

All are ceramic except the 47uF. It's aluminum obviously. I have this because of what the datasheet says about capacitor transients when this device is powered from a power supply.

The data sheet has a PCB layout guideline that I found confusing. I left the Vin and Vout traces stubbed off as this hasn't been integrated into the circuit yet. I've included a close up on the pins so you guys can see the pin names. Thanks!

[image: Top layer.]

[image: Bottom]

[image: Pins]

Comment: Ok, so what is the specific problem that you see? At a glance it looks like you followed typical layout topology for a SMPS IC. Are you concerned about noise at Vout? Linear Technology has great datasheets with lots of useful data plus examples. What are you missing?

Comment: The radio will need better ripple rejection like an LDO as  RF Amps have poor PSRR.

Comment: A schematic example would be nice

Comment: It looks pretty good. I would swap the locations of the 1uF and 2.2uF input caps (you want the smaller geometry caps with higher self resonance frequency closer to the controller). I would also rotate the 47uF cap 90 degrees to keep its ground connection closer to the IC.

Comment: @Sparky256 I was concerned about the feedback trace running under the controllers pins on the bottom layer of the board shown in blue.  I'm concerned about EMI. I've read somewhere that certain grounds should stay isolated , then grouped to main ground at a single point, any advice? Also concerned with  ripple on Vout. The data sheet on the radio says no more than 50 mV peak to peak. Of course I want to be well under 50. If there's too much ripple, I can just add more capacitors close to Vout without any changes in EMI correct?

Comment: @Sunnyskyguy EE75 Correct, the data sheet on the radio says no more than 60 mV peak to peak. Of course I want to be well under 60. If there's too much ripple, I was going to add more caps to Cout before dropping voltage down to 3.3 to feed the radio. There will also be caps next to the pin Vin on the radio. Should I keep buck circuit far from the radio?

Comment: @Laptop2d Yes I'm sorry. I'm just in the stage of grouping components together. Haven't even ran traces. Wanted to make sure all layouts are good before hand.

Comment: 60mV/100mA = 0.6 Ohm so a series T=RC of 10x time Tx duration will work too with a 60 mOhm cap. and R(+L) chosen for Tx duration.

Comment: A 2.2uF Ceramic and 47uF e-cap will not have a low ESR at Tx frequency (900MHz)  Try 47pF//470pF//47nF and larger series R. Yes it may need shielding to prevent phase noise as RF Tx have poor PSRR and inductive loops.

Comment: @Sunnyskyguy EE75 The radio manual says that if you use a switching supply, keep it above 500KHz and  use a 1uF, 10uF, and 47pF cap at Vin of the radio. Since I'm already using these caps at radio Vin, should I still place them at Vin of the buck as you stated?

Comment: No that's good at the Tx, series RL of feed needs to ensure not self resonant by suitable series R to lower Q also add ferrite beads

Comment: Excellent! Thank you for the help. I tried moving into a discussion but I dont have enough reputations. You stated "R(+L) chosen for Tx duration." What formula do I need? The only formula I can find is the RL to find Impedance. How do I choose RL for TX duration?